# Command buttons position - UI design

Tags: design-patterns, user-interface

Which design do you use? What is the size of a button? In which order?

Do you prefer

- A=OK
- B=Cancel

or

- A=Cancel
- B=OK

Do you use "Windows" button size: 80x24 px or your own?

[Design 1 http://www.quercus-lab.com/images/so/ui_1.png](http://www.quercus-lab.com/images/so/ui_1.png) [Design 2 http://www.quercus-lab.com/images/so/ui_2.png](http://www.quercus-lab.com/images/so/ui_2.png) [Design 3 http://www.quercus-lab.com/images/so/ui_3.png](http://www.quercus-lab.com/images/so/ui_3.png) [Design 4 http://www.quercus-lab.com/images/so/ui_4.png](http://www.quercus-lab.com/images/so/ui_4.png)

Comment: Is this for a GUI running on Windows?

Comment: In this context; yes. But you are welcome to share your opinion or experience if you think you can contribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stick to the windows standard.

OK | Cancel | Apply

Use the same size button where possible.

Right align them, below the content of the window.

Use the UI in the Windows Control Panel (Display Settings / Date & Time / Keyboard) as an example.

Comment: I'm using this scheme (option #2) but I've seen all of the above options. Even the "Cancel | OK" arrangement. There must be some further reading on this topic. UI should be uniform as much as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Option #2 is fairly standardized. Always put OK before Cancel.

[Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511453.aspx) recommends 75pix by 23pix for both buttons.

Answer (score 2):

First option.

Check Microsoft Windows User Experience Interaction Guidelines: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa511268.aspx